error establishing database for all wordpress on same instance
i am facing the issue of 3 WordPress websites on the same Amazon s3 instance.
when I open wp-admin in all of them, it shows an error in the database connection.
frontend is all working ok. it's just a backend I am facing the issue.

The database connection should be the same. Do you have caching set up e.g. Cloudfront? Your front end origin server might be broken too, but the cached version is still working.

Oh you said S3 instance. Did you mean EC2 instance? S3 is static. If you have a static copy of your site on S3 then it wouldn't notice if the database broke.

The obvious questions though are: 1) is the database configuration correct? 2) is the database running?. Can you connect to the database from elsewhere, and from a command-line client on the server you're running WordPress on? Where is the database, on the same box or on RDS? Are there firewalls / VPC security rules between the host server and the database? etc.

First of all, you should check the DB Configuration at wp-config.php, is the name and the db user+pw correct? Does the DB User have all the necessary permissions to the DB? Is the DB Server running at all?
You find more info how wp config should like over here:
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214693268-WordPress-wp-config-php-overview

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
